# Manipulating html input forms with CSS?

Tags: html, css

So currently I'm trying to edit the general layout and look of html input forms. Heres a snippet of my code for my html input forms:

```
<p> <form action='register.php' method="POST"></p>
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" />Last Name: <input type="text"     name="lastName"/></p>
<p>Address: <input type="text" name="address" /></p>
<p>City: <input type="text" name="city" /></p>
```

And the css that edits this is:

```
#Address, #emailAddress, #password, #confirmPassword, #firstName, #lastName{
width:50%;
outline: double 1px #FFA500;  
height:16px; 
padding:10px;  
}
```

Problem is, nothing changes with this code. Shouldn't this change my html input forms?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `id` attribute instead of the `name` attribute on your html.

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd be much better to define a style for all of your `input` elements at once:

```
input { 
    width: 50%;
    outline: double 1px #FFA500;  
    height: 16px; 
    padding: 10px; }
```

You should read up on [CSS selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref).

Comment: Thanks. This is good but I have custom parameters for each (they are all going to look different a little bit)

Comment: Still, it makes sense to define a base-style if you're sharing styles. As others have said, if you're looking for greater specificity look into using `id` or `class` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some quick observations:

- improper nesting of elements. Example, opened form tag within paragraph tag. Also, form tag isn't closed
- use "id" attribute instead of "name"
- be sure that #Address matches the input id (currently, it doesn't)
- city input id isn't reflected in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an ID or class to the input.

Remember, with CSS;

ID = #object

Class = .object

`<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />`

Comment: I knew i was missing something! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, as @Wex mentioned, it'll save you time by defining a style for all of your `input` elements at the same time with one selector. Take a look at the code he posted.